# How parse String to JObject ignoring Time Zone

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a String of json and need convert to JObject.

Example:

```
String result = ""{"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Municipio__c","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Municipio__c/a0V2C000000gIgzUAE"},"Id":"a0V2C000000gIgzUAE","LastModifiedDate":"2017-08-01T18:12:04.000+0000"}]}";"

var json = JObject.Parse(result);
```

But in the moment of the convertion, the **LastModifiedDate** has changed the value to my **Time Zone**.

Like that:

```
{{
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Municipio__c",
        "url": "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Municipio__c/a0V2C000000gIgzUAE"
      },
      "Id": "a0V2C000000gIgzUAE",
      "LastModifiedDate": "2017-08-01T15:12:04-03:00"
    }
  ]
}}
```

The hour was changed: **18:12:04** (hh:MM:ss) to **15:12:04** (hh:MM:ss).

Is there a way to ignore the Time Zone on the **parse**?

Comment: this looks strange to me, are you sure that's all?

Comment: Yes. That is a feature @MarcoSalerno

Comment: `JObject.Parse` doesn't modify strings. *It can't*. Strings are immutable. Where did the modified string come from? Besides - the time hasn't changed. It's EXACTLY the same.

Comment: It is the string representation in the debugger when you hover over the `JObject` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @PatrickHofman which is the same instance in both cases. Besides, the *string representation* doesn't mean the underlying value has changed. The debugger may be displaying the value using the user's locale, because parsing return a local or undefined datetime. It's no different that the questions about replacing nonexistend newlines

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They are not the same at my end. It appears the parser converts it to local time and then JSON.NET shows it as the local time in the debugger.

Comment: @PatrickHofman 18:12:04+00:00 is the same time value as 15:12:04-03:00. How this is formatted into a string, depends into the object's type (is it DateTime?) and if it's DateTime, on its Kind. What is the value's DateTimeKind?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmzbi.png. Kind = Local

Comment: @Lnacer an even better option is to parse the date value as a DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `JsonConvert` with the appropriate `DateTimeZoneHandling`:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
                       ( result
                       , new JsonSerializerSettings()
                         { DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
                         }
                       );
```

Answer (score 2):

The time *instances* are the same. `18:12:04+00:00` is the same as `15:12:04-03:00` and `21:12:04+03:00` (the current offset in Greece).

The default behaviour when parsing date values is to generate a local `DateTime` value, ie its [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) property will be DatTimeKind.Local`. The other [DateTimeKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) values are UTC and Unspecified.

That doesn't mean that the value *changed*. `Local` is a relative term though - without knowing the actual offset, it's easy to misinterpret it.

As Patrick Hofman explained, you can specify that UTC is used by setting the `DateTimeZoneHandling` setting.

An even better way is to specify that `DateTimeOffset` will be used instead of `DateTime` by using the `DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset` property. This will return preserve the original timezone information :

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{ 
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
};
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( result, settings);
```

In this case, the value will be a [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) with the original time and an offset of `00:00`.

I'm using `dynamic` here to reduce casting noise:

```
var settings=new JsonSerializerSettings{ 
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
};

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( result, settings);
var value=(DateTimeOffset)(json.records[0].LastModifiedDate.Value);

Console.WriteLine("{0:o}",value);
```

This will return :

```
2017-08-01T18:12:04.0000000+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JObject.Load()` method by passing into it a JsonReader configured for `DateTimeOffset` parsing. Here, for example, is a corrected version of the [Parse method](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/13.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L468):

```
static JObject ParseWithDateTimeOffset(string json, JsonLoadSettings? settings)
{
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
    {
        reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset;
        JObject o = JObject.Load(reader, settings);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Any content encountered here other than a comment will throw in the reader.
        }

        return o;
    }
}
```